# Kommata mit Partizipien

Tags: comma, past-participle

Bitte sagen Sie mir, ob wir im Deutschen mit Partizipien Kommata verwenden (vor und nach Partizipien).
Meine Beispiele für Sie, damit Sie mir sagen können, wo Kommata sein sollen:

> 1. Das Geld von mir gefunden wurde gestohlen.
> 2. Das Geld gefunden von mir wurde gestohlen.
> 3. Das von mir gefundene Geld wurde gestohlen.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8265/placing-words-between-article-and-noun-common-in-german

Answer (score 9):

Steht das Partizip nach dem Beschriebenen, stehen Kommas um die gesamte Phrase [(Regel D112)](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D112):

> 1. Das Geld, von mir gefunden, wurde gestohlen.
> 2. Das Geld, gefunden von mir, wurde gestohlen.

Steht es vor dem Beschriebenen, darf kein Komma gesetzt werden.

> 3. Das von mir gefundene Geld wurde gestohlen.

Zu den ersten beiden Sätzen 1 und 2: Das sind beides Einschübe, also bedeuten sie in etwa

> Das Geld wurde gestohlen. Ich hatte es gefunden.

und nicht, wie der letzte Satz 3

> Das Geld, das ich gefunden hatte, wurde gestohlen.

Im Deutschen setzt man Partizipien generell lieber vor das Beschriebene;
die ersten beiden Sätze klingen daher etwas seltsam. Nur Satz 3 klingt natürlich, deshalb würde ich diesen verwenden.